# Why are some weights int8 and some float32 (PyTorch 1.7 quantisation aware training)

Tags: pytorch

I trained a simple model (Conv2D + ReLU + Conv2D) with quantisation aware training in pytorch 1.7. After saving the state dict of the quantised model and opening it in Netron, I noticed that some weights are int8, but others are still float32.

For example, the Conv2D weights are int8, but the biases are float32. Why is this the case? And how does pytorch convert the biases to int8 when I load the model?

**Edit:** Below is the printed state_dict of the quantised model.

```
OrderedDict([('quant.scale', tensor([0.0058])), ('quant.zero_point', tensor([0])), ('Conv1.weight', tensor([[[[-0.1155, -0.1615, -0.0945],
          [-0.1274,  0.1510,  0.1589],
          [ 0.0775,  0.1497,  0.1274]],

         [[ 0.0775,  0.0709,  0.1339],
          [-0.1615,  0.0538,  0.0932],
          [-0.0249, -0.1011,  0.0341]],

         [[-0.1260,  0.1090, -0.0420],
          [ 0.0762, -0.1667, -0.1379],
          [-0.0105, -0.1549, -0.0026]]],


        [[[-0.0675, -0.1732,  0.0528],
          [-0.1130, -0.1482,  0.1864],
          [ 0.1746,  0.1379,  0.0528]],

         [[-0.1453,  0.1629, -0.0382],
          [-0.1159,  0.1291, -0.0088],
          [ 0.0293,  0.0719,  0.1379]],

         [[-0.0059,  0.0249, -0.0998],
          [ 0.1115, -0.1864,  0.1247],
          [-0.1423, -0.0558, -0.1643]]],


        [[[ 0.1288, -0.1288, -0.0186],
          [ 0.1248, -0.0637,  0.1434],
          [-0.1633, -0.1089,  0.1673]],

         [[-0.1700,  0.0120,  0.1474],
          [ 0.0637, -0.0359,  0.0518],
          [ 0.0664,  0.0292,  0.0637]],

         [[ 0.0996,  0.0359,  0.1129],
          [-0.1023,  0.0398,  0.1129],
          [ 0.0730, -0.1155,  0.0186]]],


        ...,


        [[[-0.1497, -0.1468,  0.0785],
          [-0.0044, -0.1061, -0.0988],
          [-0.0334,  0.0073, -0.0610]],

         [[ 0.1584, -0.0451,  0.1846],
          [ 0.0596,  0.0523, -0.1076],
          [-0.1337,  0.1453, -0.0727]],

         [[-0.0988, -0.1541,  0.1642],
          [-0.1512,  0.0669,  0.0770],
          [ 0.0959, -0.0480, -0.0363]]],


        [[[-0.0015, -0.0239, -0.0060],
          [ 0.1134, -0.0880, -0.0313],
          [-0.0507, -0.0627,  0.0462]],

         [[ 0.0224,  0.1536,  0.1164],
          [ 0.0462,  0.0164, -0.1686],
          [-0.1059, -0.1193, -0.1238]],

         [[-0.1119, -0.0403,  0.1417],
          [ 0.1895, -0.0462, -0.0746],
          [-0.0030, -0.0149, -0.1895]]],


        [[[-0.1158, -0.0868, -0.0116],
          [ 0.0767, -0.0999,  0.0449],
          [ 0.0174, -0.0999,  0.0043]],

         [[-0.0970, -0.0868,  0.0318],
          [ 0.1838, -0.0883,  0.0883],
          [ 0.0897,  0.0666, -0.0897]],

         [[-0.1129, -0.1838,  0.0174],
          [-0.1332, -0.0275, -0.1650],
          [-0.1172, -0.0825,  0.0449]]]], size=(128, 3, 3, 3),
       dtype=torch.qint8, quantization_scheme=torch.per_channel_affine,
       scale=tensor([0.0013, 0.0015, 0.0013, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015,
        0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015,
        0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0012,
        0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0015,
        0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0015,
        0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0013, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0014, 0.0015,
        0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015,
        0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0014, 0.0015,
        0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015,
        0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0013, 0.0014,
        0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015,
        0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015,
        0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0015,
        0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015, 0.0014, 0.0015,
        0.0015, 0.0014], dtype=torch.float64),
       zero_point=tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
       axis=0)), ('Conv1.bias', tensor([-0.0076, -0.1628,  0.0198,  0.0671,  0.0580, -0.0119,  0.1381,  0.1515,
         0.0006, -0.1816, -0.0398, -0.1390, -0.1904, -0.1584, -0.1862, -0.0725,
         0.1018,  0.0192,  0.0459,  0.0122, -0.0790,  0.0689,  0.1705, -0.0765,
        -0.0684,  0.1773, -0.1782, -0.0136, -0.0989, -0.1515, -0.1222, -0.1603,
         0.0768, -0.0196,  0.1086,  0.1526,  0.1713, -0.1683,  0.0665, -0.1556,
         0.0356, -0.1606,  0.1206,  0.0589,  0.1702, -0.1242,  0.1160,  0.1241,
        -0.0293,  0.0719, -0.1161, -0.0638,  0.1791,  0.0327,  0.0470, -0.1005,
        -0.0801,  0.0491, -0.0330,  0.1024, -0.1336, -0.1146,  0.1859, -0.0381,
         0.0134, -0.0438, -0.0574, -0.1637,  0.1240, -0.0087, -0.1361, -0.0820,
        -0.1605, -0.0396,  0.0912,  0.1553, -0.0816,  0.0428,  0.0644,  0.0374,
        -0.1021,  0.0983,  0.0982, -0.1161,  0.1612, -0.0651,  0.0618,  0.1647,
        -0.0890,  0.1622, -0.0400,  0.0981,  0.0385, -0.1839,  0.0367, -0.0605,
        -0.1760, -0.0574,  0.1601,  0.1603,  0.1676,  0.0800,  0.1583, -0.1492,
         0.0910, -0.0997, -0.0313, -0.0552,  0.1784, -0.1193, -0.0585, -0.1764,
         0.0099, -0.0066,  0.0491,  0.0959, -0.0493,  0.1617,  0.1466,  0.1692,
         0.1415,  0.0424, -0.1162,  0.1862,  0.0290, -0.0040,  0.0939,  0.1713],
       requires_grad=True)), ('Conv1.scale', tensor(0.0187)), ('Conv1.zero_point', tensor(75)), ('Conv2.weight', tensor([[[[-0.0155, -0.0042,  0.0136],
          [-0.0194,  0.0005,  0.0187],
          [-0.0058,  0.0044,  0.0148]],

         [[-0.0226,  0.0053, -0.0247],
          [ 0.0079,  0.0226, -0.0129],
          [ 0.0014,  0.0044,  0.0164]],

         [[ 0.0185,  0.0247,  0.0046],
          [ 0.0122,  0.0259, -0.0148],
          [ 0.0226,  0.0173,  0.0083]],

         ...,

         [[-0.0215,  0.0051, -0.0136],
          [-0.0159,  0.0000, -0.0203],
          [-0.0219, -0.0141, -0.0282]],

         [[-0.0065,  0.0085, -0.0139],
          [-0.0028, -0.0039,  0.0171],
          [ 0.0254,  0.0152,  0.0282]],

         [[-0.0293,  0.0049,  0.0002],
          [ 0.0245, -0.0046, -0.0042],
          [ 0.0240,  0.0236, -0.0256]]],


        [[[-0.0247,  0.0194,  0.0127],
          [ 0.0134,  0.0240,  0.0288],
          [ 0.0136, -0.0198, -0.0120]],

         [[ 0.0005, -0.0088,  0.0044],
          [-0.0014, -0.0101,  0.0062],
          [-0.0053,  0.0293,  0.0085]],

         [[-0.0201, -0.0101,  0.0083],
          [-0.0201, -0.0263, -0.0184],
          [-0.0113, -0.0062,  0.0062]],

         ...,

         [[ 0.0260,  0.0288, -0.0002],
          [ 0.0127,  0.0272,  0.0270],
          [-0.0168, -0.0157, -0.0092]],

         [[-0.0065,  0.0067, -0.0164],
          [ 0.0124, -0.0244,  0.0035],
          [ 0.0293, -0.0028, -0.0152]],

         [[-0.0154,  0.0014, -0.0196],
          [ 0.0078, -0.0044,  0.0115],
          [-0.0048, -0.0071, -0.0088]]],


        [[[ 0.0069, -0.0099,  0.0259],
          [ 0.0268,  0.0102,  0.0192],
          [ 0.0173, -0.0206,  0.0203]],

         [[-0.0016, -0.0183, -0.0217],
          [ 0.0226,  0.0129, -0.0092],
          [-0.0018,  0.0166,  0.0164]],

         [[-0.0229,  0.0201, -0.0187],
          [-0.0074,  0.0183, -0.0273],
          [-0.0139, -0.0023, -0.0226]],

         ...,

         [[ 0.0224, -0.0099, -0.0196],
          [ 0.0157,  0.0018, -0.0194],
          [ 0.0016,  0.0201,  0.0044]],

         [[-0.0217, -0.0252, -0.0141],
          [-0.0116,  0.0270, -0.0085],
          [ 0.0231,  0.0291,  0.0153]],

         [[ 0.0148, -0.0215, -0.0116],
          [ 0.0155, -0.0049, -0.0166],
          [-0.0254,  0.0032, -0.0125]]]], size=(3, 128, 3, 3),
       dtype=torch.qint8, quantization_scheme=torch.per_channel_affine,
       scale=tensor([0.0002, 0.0002, 0.0002], dtype=torch.float64),
       zero_point=tensor([0, 0, 0]), axis=0)), ('Conv2.bias', tensor([-0.0076,  0.0025, -0.0067], requires_grad=True)), ('Conv2.scale', tensor(0.0026)), ('Conv2.zero_point', tensor(27))])
```

Apparently the conv weights are also float, for some reason Netron converts those to int8.

Comment: Can you check the type of the weights in PyTorch itself? So, we can isolate the issue within PyTorch and confirm that netron is not changing something.

Comment: I added the printout in the question